# Travel visa rejection and acceptance data availability

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

I am searching for data for standard visitor visa rejections/acceptances by different countries. In general any visa rejections/acceptances data wouldn't hurt. But my primary aim is travel visas.

I searched and contacted a few people to get information for the schengen region: https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/policies/schengen-borders-and-visa/visa-policy_en (2009-2022 year data)

Can someone tell me if there are any comprehensive datasets which contain the information I am asking for different countries? Or any research articles people have done with such data?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

| Country | Human-readable | Machine-Readable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Australia | [Australia's Home Affairs](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/research-and-statistics/statistics/visa-statistics) | - |
| Canada | - | [Canada's Open-Data](https://search.open.canada.ca/opendata/?_organization_limit=0&organization=cic&sort=metadata_modified+desc&search_text=Temporary+Resident+Application+Processing&page=1) |
| France | [France Interior Minister](https://www.immigration.interieur.gouv.fr/Info-ressources/Etudes-et-statistiques/Chiffres-cles-sejour-visas-eloignements-asile-acces-a-la-nationalite) | [France's Open-Data](https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/organizations/ministere-de-linterieur-et-des-outre-mer/?q=visa&sort=-created#/datasets) |
| NZ | [Immigration Department](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/about-us/research-and-statistics/statistics) | [Migration Data Explorer](https://mbienz.shinyapps.io/migration_data_explorer/) |
| Schengen (whole) | - | [EU Home Affairs](https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/policies/schengen-borders-and-visa/visa-policy_en) |
| UK | [Home Office](https://www.gov.uk/government/collections/immigration-statistics-quarterly-release) | [Home Office](https://www.gov.uk/government/collections/immigration-statistics-quarterly-release) |
| US | [State Department](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal/visa-law0/visa-statistics.html) | - |

Comment: For the US a lot of the data has only issuances, not refusals (or applications), but refusals can be found [here](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal/visa-law0/visa-statistics/nonimmigrant-visa-statistics/nonimmigrant-b-visa-adjusted-refusal-rates-by-nationality.html) by nationality and [here](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal/visa-law0/visa-statistics/nonimmigrant-visa-statistics.html) by category.

Comment: Worth making this a Community Wiki?

Comment: Anyone has data related to Israel and India too?  @jcaron