# The total non-immigrant visa applications to US

Tags: visas, usa, statistics

I recently asked a question: [Travel visa rejection and acceptance data availability](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/181464/travel-visa-rejection-and-acceptance-data-availability) here in this forum regarding visa rejections and acceptances in different countries. But I would like to also see the total number of non-immigrant visa application sorted yearwise, and different nation wise. The below link is an answer from my previous query.

https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal/visa-law0/visa-statistics.html

But I can only see issuance/rejections. Maybe it talks about total applications, but I am yet to discover it. In case if that is not available here, where should I look for? Thank you. At least any estimatefrom research papers would be fine. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think those stats are published, as I can't find them on the [OIS](https://www.dhs.gov/immigration-statistics) website. For NIV, a rough estimate can likely be calculated from visa approvals + visa refusal

Comment: Isn't the number of applications equal to the sum of the numbers of issuances and rejections?  Of course, there will be some decisions in any year that result from applications in the prior year, but that may not be significant to your purpose.  Another thing to keep in mind is that some statistics are given by the country where the application was made while others are given by the country of the applicant's nationality; the two aren't necessarily the same.

Comment: Apparently, the answer to my question in the previous comment is "no"; see comments on jcaron's answer for details.

Answer (score 6):

As I indicated in a comment to the answer on your earlier question, while most of the reports only give approved visas, you’ll find full data, per category and per year, on [this page](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal/visa-law0/visa-statistics/nonimmigrant-visa-statistics.html), in the section titled “**Nonimmigrant Worldwide Issuance and Refusal Data by Visa Category**”.

The reports include the following columns:

- Visa category
- Issued
- Refused
- Total applications

For data per country, I believe you’ll have to use the data for visas issued and the refusal rate per country to extrapolate the total number of applications (it will be slightly off because there a a few minor cases other than just issued and refused):

total = issued / (1-refusal rate)

Comment: What other outcome is there besides issued and refused?

Comment: Apparently there’s a notion of “overcome” (long discussion on this topic on [this page](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal/visa-law0/visa-statistics/nonimmigrant-visa-statistics/nonimmigrant-b-visa-adjusted-refusal-rates-by-nationality.html)) and it’s possible that some applications are just not processed at all for some reason, or withdrawn. Also in the discussion on the page linked above they only count one application per person, not sure if in other places they don’t count all applications.

Comment: @phoog request retracted comes to mind. Overtaken by events (applicant died while waiting for approval) comes to mind as well.